# why is this pointer printing part of the memory address when I try to print the characters stored therein

Tags: pointers

I created a pointer:(#*n) in the main function storing a simple string literal,and printed out its value in the main function and the output was okay:(function pointers), as I expected, BUT, when I passed the pointer to a function:(#topic) as an argument, then tried to print the original value of the pointer in the new function, I had a strange output with part of the memory address at the end of the new output:(#function pointers144).
I speculate it could be a stack issue but I'm not certain. I'd appreciate some feedback on what is really happening.

```c
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv);
void topic(char *arg);
int F(int a,int b);
//int sum;

int F(int a,int b){
    int sum;
    sum = a+b;
    return sum;
}

void topic(char *arg){
    
    char *p = malloc(20*sizeof(char));
     if (p == NULL){

        printf("Oops! There eas a problem with memory allocation.");
        return;
    }
    
    do{

        printf("Entre your name:");
        scanf("%s",p);
    }
    while ((!!isalnum(*p)) == 0);

    printf("Hello, %s, today's topic id is %s",p,arg);
    free(p);
}

int main(int argc,char **argv){
    
    printf("the name of the program is:%s\n",argv[0]);
    printf("The argument count is %i\n",argc);
    
    int sum;
    char* n = {"function pointers"};
    
    printf("the value of n is: %s\n",n);
    
    void (*t)(char*);
    t = topic;
    t(n);

    int (*o)(int,int);
    o = F;
    sum = o(97,47);
    
    printf("%i",sum);
}
```

Comment: its your final printf in main - put a \n at the end of  `topic id is %s`

Answer (score 0):

As @pm100 suggests, the only problem is that you're missing a `\n`: Change

```
    printf("Hello, %s, today's topic id is %s",p,arg);
```

into:

```
    printf("Hello, %s, today's topic id is %s\n",p,arg);
```

Note that the "144" is something you yourself print, in `main()`, after having called `topic()`.